# How to update pydantic model from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I have a pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    value : str = 'Some value'
```

And I need to update this model using a dictionary (not create).

I tried updating the model using `class.__dict__`, but after updating that's just a dictionary, not model values.

So I need something like this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    value : str = 'Some value'

model = MyModel()
update_model(model = model, data = {'value' : 'Bla bla bla'}) # here must be a function to update model :D

print(model.__dict__)
{'value' : 'Bla bla bla'}
```

Comment: Hi, why you want to update model instead model instance? Please describe your case, bocuse I believe you will need much simpler solution than you think.

Comment: i want to update a model instance

Answer (score 8):

**Update**:

[`models.copy(...)`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modelcopy) has been depricated, use [`model_copy(...)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#model_copy) instead.

---

You can do this by updating `__dict__` attribute directly, for example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    value: str = 'Some value'


model = MyModel()

model.__dict__.update({'value': 'Bla bla bla'}) # or vars(model).update(...)

print(model.dict())
```

Another approach would be to use [`models.copy(...)`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modelcopy):

```
model = MyModel()
model = model.copy(update={'value': 'Bla bla bla'})

print(model.dict())
```

**Output:**

```
{'value': 'Bla bla bla'}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `copy()` lets you update fields that do not event exist and does not trigger the validators.

Comment: You could override the copy method to ensure that the copy process is also validated by extending the pydantic.BaseModel.

Comment: The copy method is deprecated; use `model_copy` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `model_copy`, but a new instance will be created

If you need to update the current instance, use for `setattr`.

For example:

```py
>>> class MyModel(BaseModel):
        value: str = 'Some value'

        def update(self, **new_data):
            for field, value in new_data.items():
               setattr(self, field, value)

>>> model = MyModel()

>>> model.update(value='new value')
>>> model
MyModel(value='new value')
```

Note: This method does't validate the types of new values. To enable validation, set `validate_assignment=True` to `model_config`

```py
>>> class MyModel(BaseModel):
        value: str = 'Some value'
        
        model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)

        def update(self, **new_data):
            for field, value in new_data.items():
               setattr(self, field, value)

>>> model = MyModel()

>>> model.update(value=123)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyModel
value
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=1, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.3/v/string_type
```